# Requests keeps returning 403 status, even when following evey step from api documentation

Tags: python, request

I'm trying to use Solarman API (which is a very simple API from [this](https://pro.solarmanpv.com) website) to make a simple request to access a token, but it keeps returning a 403 code. Am I doing something wrong ?

here's the code I'm trying:

```
import requests




url = 'https://api.solarmanpv.com/account/v1.0/token?appId='+appid+'&language=en'

params = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'appSecret': appsecret,
    'password': password,
    'username': username
    }


response = requests.request('POST',url,params=params)


print(response)
```

bellow, you can see how documentation demands the request

[image]

and the example given:

[image]

Comment: How do you know that the username, password & appsecret are valid?

Comment: The stuff you put in `params` should go as the body of the request. Replace `params=params` with `json=params`

Comment: Is your password sha 256?

Comment: To answer you all, appsecret is given by the company itself (solarman), username and password are the ones we use to log in, and yes, the password is the encrypted version on this case. I tried replacing params with json and I still get a 403 response. I'm trying to exhaust options here before contacting the company again

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I thought I'd post a solution here in any case. 
 I added the following header, which seemed to do the trick:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'}

url = baseurl+'account/v1.0/token?appId='+app_id+'&language=en'

data ={'appSecret':key,'email':email, 'password':password}

a = requests.post(url,json=data,headers=headers)
```